# How to assign the same vector in every row of a matrix

Tags: r

I want to put the same vector in each row of an empty matrix in R. I thought that the following would work but it doesn't. It assigns 1 to the first entry (1,1) then 0 to (2,1) then zero again to (1,2) and 1 to (2,2) etc.

`P = matrix(0,100,3)`

`P[1:2,]=c(1,0,0)`

Any ideas, how to do that?? I want to avoid loops if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `replicate` to copy directly, without needing to start with an empty matrix

```r
vec <- 1:5

t(replicate(10, vec))
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#>  [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#>  [2,]    1    2    3    4    5
#>  [3,]    1    2    3    4    5
#>  [4,]    1    2    3    4    5
#>  [5,]    1    2    3    4    5
#>  [6,]    1    2    3    4    5
#>  [7,]    1    2    3    4    5
#>  [8,]    1    2    3    4    5
#>  [9,]    1    2    3    4    5
#> [10,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

Answer (score 2):

We can `rep`licate it by the number of rows it is going to be changed

```
n <- 2
P[seq_len(n),]  <- rep(c(1,0,0), each = n)
```

---

Or it can be constructed with `matrix` call itself

```
vec <- c(1, 0, 0)
matrix(vec, 100, length(vec), byrow = TRUE)
```

Or another option is to wrap `list` and `rep`licate

```
do.call(rbind, rep(list(vec), 100))
```

Comment: I think your first approach still has the problem, the rest ones work perfectly.

Comment: @Jonathan1234 It should be `each = ` in the `rep`.  Sorry, for that

Comment: There is no problem you helped me! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Note that R recycles data as long as the integer dimensional integrity is maintained.

```
n <- 1:5
m <- matrix(n, nrow = 100, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option is using `kronecker`

```
v <- c(1, 0, 0)
t(kronecker(t(rep(1, 10)), v))
```

which gives

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    0    0
 [2,]    1    0    0
 [3,]    1    0    0
 [4,]    1    0    0
 [5,]    1    0    0
 [6,]    1    0    0
 [7,]    1    0    0
 [8,]    1    0    0
 [9,]    1    0    0
[10,]    1    0    0
```

Comment: Nice option with `kronecker`